# Unexpected type (File) of the resource with URI with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, clarity

I have a main report, and need one of the fields to be a hyperlink to another report (using that field as the parameter of the second report).

- I right clicked, and clicked `Hyperlink`
- `Link Target` - Blank
- `Link Type` - ReportExecution

Parameters:

1. **Name:** `_report`  **Expression:** `/ca_ppm/resources/PSR_MilestoneReportV2.jrxml`
2. **Name:** `program`  **Expression:** `$F{name}`

The parameter `program` is used in the sub-report to pull the information.

The expression for _report is the correct path for the `.jrxml` file of the sub-report, and I also have that `.jrxml` file marked as a resource in `Controls and Resources` for the main report...

Yet I am getting this error:

```
Unexpected type (File) of the resource with URI/ca_ppm/resources/PSR_MilestoneReportV2.jrxml
```

This seems to be a path issue.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_report needs to be a report unit with data source and son on (same type of resource/entity as the main report) and not a JRXML file resource.

And if you want to pass "program" as a parameter, you'll need to define an input control for it (in addition to the JRXML report parameter) in the target report unit.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.. The problem was as you said -- I was using the .jrxml file rather than the actual report.